# Abnormal CPU usage when using timerfd and read

Tags: c, timer, linux-kernel

I got a high CPU usage when using timerfd on my `x86` machine. This issue is randomly happened.
The weird thing is if it happened at the first time running, then will happen at every time running until reboot the system. Vice versa, if normal, then normal every time.

The linux kernel version is `5.4.44` and configured with `tickless`, `HZ=1000` and `hrtimer, hept` is enabled.

Below is the code I run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NS_IN_MS 1000000
int timer_fd;

int main(){
    struct itimerspec tspec;
    int times = 0;
    u_int64_t exp;
    timer_fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);

    tspec.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    tspec.it_interval.tv_nsec = NS_IN_MS;
    tspec.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    tspec.it_value.tv_nsec = NS_IN_MS; 
/*This will let the timer expired at the first time. But with this can easily to reproduce every time running.*/

    timerfd_settime(timer_fd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &tspec, NULL);

    while(1){
      read(timer_fd, &exp, sizeof(u_int64_t));
      times++;
      if (times == 20000)
         break; //run 20 sec.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Top says cpu 0 `sys`'s usage is `49.8%`, but a.out is only occupy 2%. And there is no process's cpu usage more than a.out.

```
top - 13:55:54 up 3 min,  4 users,  load average: 0.51, 0.32, 0.13
Tasks: 110 total,   1 running, 109 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us, 49.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 48.4 id,  0.0 wa,  1.4 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   1636.1 total,   1385.2 free,     96.0 used,    154.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    512.0 total,    512.0 free,      0.0 used.   1503.5 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
    823 root      20   0   16788    896    812 S   2.0   0.1   0:00.37 a.out    
    812 root      20   0   27804   3912   3316 S   0.3   0.2   0:00.30 htop     
    853 root      20   0   64500   4464   3840 R   0.3   0.3   0:00.01 top      
      1 root      20   0   97720  10940   8416 S   0.0   0.7   0:00.85 systemd  
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
```

The following are my try:

1. Configure kernel with rt-patch(rt27) and `full-preemptive` -> no effect.

   - Raise `ksoftirqd/0`'s priority to the highest(SCHED_FIFO 99). -> no effect.
2. Configure kernel with `low-latency` model -> no effect.
3. Configure kernel with `periodic tick` -> no effect.
4. Change clock to `REALTIME` and `BOOTTIME`. -> no effect.
5. Change `timerfd_settime` flag to 0(relative). -> no effect.
6. Use `clock_gettime() + NS_IN_MS` result as `it_value` value. -> sometimes normal, but sometimes abnormal, can not reproduce every time.
7. Its ok with kernel vision `4.14.188 and 4.18.16`. -> But not with `4.19, 5.0, 5.4 and 5.6`

Comment: Does it still happen if you only use one thread? Does `read` ever return any error?

Comment: The `read` doesn't return error and it can reproduce in one thread.

Comment: If it can reproduce in one thread then you should post the one-thread code instead, because the extra thread is irrelevant.

Comment: I updated the code. thank you for the advice.

Comment: It might be a good idea to attach a debugger (or strace) to the program when it's spinning, and examine teh result of the system calls. In particular when the the status of 'read', 'timer_fd', and what is 'errno' value after each system call. The current program does not check for any errors on system calls.